# CSS Menu on ipad only is left aligning, i need center align. All desktop browsesrs center align, not sure why tablet is changing it

Tags: css

i need some help with my css file. My menu on every desktop browser is center aligning beautifully and text is right aligning. However the minute i pull it up on an ipad with safari browser my menu (as a whole) all of a sudden the menu is left aligned. Now when i test on safari from a desktop the menu is center aligned. For the life of me i can't figure out which selector i should be editing or adding. There is no responsive code because the system i am using right now doesn't support it however it should pull up the same way on the desktop and it's not...

```
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu li,
#cssmenu span,
#cssmenu a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
#cssmenu {
  line-height: 1;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  background: #343e48;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #48515A 0%, #343e48 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #48515A), color-stop(100%, #343e48));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #48515A 0%, #343e48 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #48515A 0%, #343e48 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #48515A 0%, #343e48 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #48515A 0%, #343e48 100%);
  border-bottom: 2px solid #343e48;
  width: 967px;   
}

#cssmenu:after,
#cssmenu ul:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
#cssmenu a {
  background: #343e48;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #48515A 0%, #343e48 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #48515A), color-stop(100%, #343e48));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #48515A 0%, #343e48 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #48515A 0%, #343e48 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #48515A 0%, #343e48 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #48515A 0%, #343e48 100%);
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  font-family: Gotham, 'Open Sans', Calibri, sans-serif;
  padding: 19px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#cssmenu ul {
  list-style: none;
}
#cssmenu > ul {
  font-size: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-center {
  text-align: center;
}
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li {
  float: none;
}
#cssmenu.align-center ul ul {
  text-align: left;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul {
  text-align: right;
}
  #cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 18px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid #d56127;
  margin-left: -10px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:first-child > a {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:first-child > a,
#cssmenu.align-center > ul > li:first-child > a {
  border-radius: 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right > ul > li:last-child > a {
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li:hover > a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #343e48;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #343e48;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px #343e48;
  background: #D56127;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #D56127 0%, #D56127 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #D56127), color-stop(100%, #D56127));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #D56127 0%, #D56127 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #D56127 0%, #D56127 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #D56127 0%, #D56127 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #D56127 0%, #D56127 100%);
}
#cssmenu .has-sub {
  z-index: 1;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right .has-sub ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li {
  *margin-bottom: -1px;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #d56127;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #df8050;
  font-size: 18px;
  filter: none;
  display: block;
  line-height: 120%;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:hover a {
  background: #aa4d1f;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub:hover > ul {
  display: block;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
#cssmenu.align-right .has-sub .has-sub ul,
#cssmenu.align-right ul ul ul {
  left: auto;
  right: 100%;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a {
  background: #aa4d1f;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #df8050;
}
#cssmenu .has-sub .has-sub ul li a:hover {
  background: #94441b;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.last > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu ul ul ul li.last > a,
#cssmenu ul ul ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu .has-sub ul li.last > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```